# A sequence converging uniformly to 0 so that Fatou's Lemma is a strict inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

I have to find a sequence of measurable functions such that it converges uniformly to zero but Fatou's Lemma is a strict inequality.

I can find a sequence of functions that converges pointwise to $0$ so that Fatou's Lemma is strict. However, when I want it converges uniformly to zero, I got stuck.

Please help me. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd recommend trying to find characteristic functions which do the job.

Comment: A sequence of functions that converges pointwise to 0 so that Fatou's lemma is strict is $f_n = n \chi_{(0,1/n]}$ on $[0,1]$. But you know, it doesn't converge uniformly to 0.

Comment: $f_n=n\chi_{(n,n+1)}$.

Comment: @FactorY That example stretches the function vertically--what if you stretch it horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f_n=\frac1n\chi_{(0,n)}$ we have $f_n\rightarrow0$ uniformly since $$\left|f_n-f_m\right|<\frac1n+\frac1m<\frac2N$$for $n,m>N$.

Then $$0=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}dm<\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}dm=1$$and we get strict inequality in Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Your example is the same as Nick F's idea above. I try and it works. However, I don't know why do you prove a sequence converging to $0$ like this. I just simply prove $|f_n - 0| < 1/n \le 1/N < \varepsilon$, for all $n \ge N$ on the set.

Comment: You’re right. I used Cauchy criterion for no particular reason. It gives the same proof in this case. It can be more useful if we don’t know the limit of $f_n$.